# What's the difference between 'get out of my car' and 'get out from my car'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, expressions, prepositions

Are they telling the same thing or is there any subtle difference between them? thanks.

Comment: "Get out from" a car / room / place is not idiomatic in modern English as commonly used worldwide, and '**get out of**' is the appropriate usage. However people do use 'get out from' when it is immediately followed by  words like under / behind / underneath etc (as noted by mike_on_stack in the answer below) where 'from' is associated with what follows and not directly applied to the car itself: *get out from under* that crane before you are flattened by a ton of (whatever is in that shipping container) // *would you kindly **get out from behind** that newspaper and call our son's Headmaster?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a comment to the original question and is not an answer per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of each phrase is valid under specific circumstances.

1. **Get out of my car** is used when the person saying it is inside the car and telling someone else (who is also in the car) to get out. Usually this is said with a negative tone.
2. **Get out from my car** is weirdly worded. **Get out from UNDER my car** is used. Would suggest never using **Get out from my car**.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference I can see is that "get out from my car" is not how English is generally spoken. It's meaning is clear enough, but it sounds non-idomatic. Everyone I know would say "get out of my car".

Here is a [non scholarly reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNgcYGgtf8M) ;)